# Transitive dependencies on bundles?

Tags: maven-2, maven, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

when using `bundle` as the packaging of a maven artifact, I seem to lose all information about transitive dependencies. So if artifact A depends on artifact B and B is packaged as a bundle, A does not see the maven dependencies that B has. This leads to lots of issues with maven plugins used in A's POM that need this information (such as maven-dependency-plugin or maven-eclipse-plugin). The only workaround I have found is to embed the dependencies into the bundle (usign Embed-Dependencies in the configuration of the felix bundle plugin). I don't want to do that, however, I want to keep them in their own files. Is there another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this behaviour [is a bug](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-1634), which has already been fixed in the latest (as of now unreleased) version of the maven-bundle-plugin. So in case anyone here stumbles upon it, simply upgrade to the latest version of the plugin (either build it yourself or get it from the [apache snapshot repository](http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) ) and the problem will go away.